# Some times i am getting wrong latitude and longitude when clicking right callout button

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, annotations, mkmapview

Whenever i am clicking on a annotation view throught right callout accesory button i am getting latitude and longitude of that point, working fine but some times its showing another pin latitude and longitude.

why this was happening?

```
MKAnnotationView GetViewForAnnotation (MKMapView mapView, NSObject annotation)
 {

                    if (annotation is MKUserLocation)

                        return null;

                    // handle our two custom annotations

                    if (imgHazardType==1) 
                    {

                        const string PoliceAnnotationIdentifier = "PoliceAnnotationIdentifier";

                        MKAnnotationView pinView = (MKAnnotationView)mapView.DequeueReusableAnnotation (PoliceAnnotationIdentifier);

                        if (pinView == null) 
                        {

                            MKAnnotationView policeannotationView = new MKAnnotationView (annotation, PoliceAnnotationIdentifier);

                            policeannotationView.CanShowCallout = true;

                            UIImage flagImage = UIImage.FromFile ("Images/cop-point.png");

                            UIButton infobutton =UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure);

                            policeannotationView.RightCalloutAccessoryView= infobutton;

                            infobutton.TouchUpInside+= (sender, e) => 
                            {

                                    NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString((annotation as Annotation).Coordinate.Latitude.ToString (),"lat");
                                    NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString((annotation as Annotation).Coordinate.Longitude.ToString (),"lon");


                            } ;


                            RectangleF resizeRect;
                            resizeRect.Size = flagImage.Size;

                            SizeF maxSize = View.Bounds.Inset (AnnotationPadding, AnnotationPadding).Size;

                            maxSize.Height -= NavigationController.NavigationBar.Frame.Size.Height - CalloutHeight;

                            if (resizeRect.Size.Width > maxSize.Width)

                                resizeRect.Size = new SizeF (maxSize.Width, resizeRect.Size.Height / resizeRect.Size.Width * maxSize.Width);

                            if (resizeRect.Size.Height > maxSize.Height)

                                resizeRect.Size = new SizeF (resizeRect.Size.Width / resizeRect.Size.Height * maxSize.Height, maxSize.Height);

                            resizeRect.Location = PointF.Empty;
                            UIGraphics.BeginImageContext (resizeRect.Size);
                            flagImage.Draw (resizeRect);

                            UIImage resizedImage = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext ();
                            UIGraphics.EndImageContext ();
                            policeannotationView.Image = resizedImage;
                            policeannotationView.Opaque = false;
                            pinViews.Add (policeannotationView);

                            return policeannotationView;

                        }  
                        else 
                        {

                            pinView.Annotation = annotation;

                        }

                        return pinView;

                    } 

            return null;
        }
```

Comment: The code is not helpful since we do not know what (or when, or how) `annotation` is being set to a value.

Comment: Please show the entire `mapView:didSelectAnnotationView:` function.

Comment: now i attached all my code i am storing clicked annotation latitude and longitude in user defaults

Comment: You deleted the question. And the code you have provided is not the code for selecting an annotation.

Comment: give me the code or link for clicking on any annotation, gives its latitude and longitude.

Comment: OK last try: You need to show the code you are using for *selecting* the annotation. If you were using regular Objective-C, not this C# stuff, the function you need to show is called 'mapView:didSelectAnnotationView:'. If you can't show that code no-one can help you.

Comment: I am not using any code like 'mapView:didSelectAnnotationView:'   for selecting the annotation.I am just added RightCalloutAccessoryView button for annotation with some title, and  retriving its latitude and longitude in that button click.

Comment: To handle annotation click, i am using this code.                      http://docs.xamarin.com/iOS/Recipes/Content_Controls/Map_View/Handle_Annotation_Click